# В чём отличия package и module в Go (golang)?

Tags: golang

> Declare a main package (a package is a way to group functions).

В чем отличие **пакета** заданного кляузой `package`, импортируемого "**пакета**" (?) при помощи `import` и **модуля** созданного `go mod init module_name`?

- https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/getting-started
- https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules
- https://golangdocs.com/packages-in-golang

Comment: golangbyexample.com: Packages and Modules in Go (Golang) – [Part 1](https://golangbyexample.com/packages-modules-go-first/), [Part 2](https://golangbyexample.com/packages-modules-go-second/). Не особо вникал, но вдруг может что-нибудь прояснить.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1527425/В-чём-разница-между-пакетами-и-модулями-golang

Answer (score 0):

Пакет (*package*) — набор типов, функций,
и значений, относящийся к какой-либо задаче. Как правило, не
считая тестовых пакетов, в одной директории находится один
пакет. Модуль
(*module*) — *версионированный* набор
пакетов. Как правило, это один репозиторий, хотя один репозиторий может
содержать несколько мажорных версий. Чтобы иметь возможность использовать
пакеты из модуля, этот модуль и его минимальная версия должны быть добавлены
в `go.mod` вашего модуля.