# В чём разница между пакетами и модулями Golang?

Tags: golang, модули, пакеты

Разбираюсь с golang, система линковки и подклчения сторонних библиотек несколько непонятна. Почему-то только с github можно подключать или я не разобрался. Ещё везде какая-то попорченная терминология с пакетами и модулями. Пожалуйста, объясните что есть что и зачем оно нужно, разницу при линковке и можно ли что-то подключить не с github?
Пожалуйста, прикрепите свои русскоязычные источники. Достаточно много англоязычной литературы, однако с переводом на русский всё ,видимо,несколько путается.

Comment: Вот можете посмотреть файл [`go.mod`](https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea/blob/main/go.mod) проекта gitea, там зависимости не только с github.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Модуль - это дерево пакетов. Имя модуля задаётся в `go.mod`

## Модули и пакеты как каталоги с файлами

Пакет - это набор исходных .go файлов, находящихся в одном каталоге и с одинаковой директивой `package`.

Файлы для одного пакета обязаны находиться в одном каталоге. Полное имя для пакета строится из имени модуля и пути к каталогу с файлами. Например,

- в `go.mod` написано `module example.org/mylib`,
- тогда все пакеты из модуля `example.org/mylib` должны быть в дочерних каталогах относительно `go.mod`.
- и путь к каталогу определяет имя пакета.

Например, в дереве исходников вашей библиотеки есть файлы в каталоге `./cmd/root`. Тогда эти файлы должны быть либо с директивой `package root`, либо `package root_test`. И полное имя пакета для этих файлов будет либо `example.org/mylib/cmd/root`, либо `example.org/mylib/cmd/root_test`[1].

## Области видимости в модулях и пакетах

Имена, начинающиеся с маленькой буквы, видны только в пакете. Другие пакеты, даже в том же самом модуле, не имеют доступа к этим сущностям.

Примеры. В пакете `example.org/mylib/cmd/root` объявлены:

- структура `type struct myCommand`. Эту структуру можно использовать только в коде, относящемуся к `package root`.
- глобальная переменная `var flagConfig = "config"` так же видна лишь в пакете `root`. Аналогично с именами функций и методов.
- поле структуры `type struct Stuff { buf []byte ... }`: структура `Stuff` видна всем, кто импортирует пакет `example.org/mylib/cmd/root`, но только внутри пакета `root` можно обращаться к полю `buf`. (на самом деле до поля `buf` можно добраться через рефлексию, но это совершенно другая история)

Пакеты, содержащие `/internal/` внутри пути, видны только в модуле. Никакой другой модуль не может использовать объявения из этих пакетов. Попробуйте как-нибудь вызывать функцию `edwards25519.NewScalar()` из пакета `crypto/internal/edwards25519` и полюбуйтесь на ошибку компиляции `could not import crypto/internal/edwards25519`

## Поиск пакетов

### Поиск пакетов в сети

Для автоматического поиска пакетов в Гугле придумали [протокол goproxy](https://go.dev/ref/mod#goproxy-protocol)
Он реализован в GitHub, поэтому любой модуль, размещённый там, автоматически будет найден командами `go get`, `go mod tidy`, `go build` и подобными.

Но никто не ограничивает вас пользоваться только гитхабом. К примеру, [поддержка goproxy есть в GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/go_proxy/). Разворачиваете у себя на сервере гитлаб, настраиваете домены и прокси - и готово, `go get` начинает находить модули с вашим доменным именем.

### Поиск пакетов в файловой системе

#### replace

Можно развернуть исходники стороннего модуля у себя в файловой системе, а в `go.mod` прописать зависимость с `replace`:

```
require example.org/some/module v1.01.02
replace example.org/some/module => ../some_module_src
```

В этом случае `go build` вообще не полезет в интернет, а возьмёт исходники модуля `example.org/some/module` из каталога `../some_module_src`

#### Workspace

Воркспейс позволяет находить модули в соседних каталогах.

Например, вы создаёте приложение в модуле `example.org/myapp` и используете библиотеку `example.org/mylib`. Понятное дело, что автоматический поиск пакетов не может обнаружить `example.org/mylib`, ибо в домене `example.org` отсутствует Go прокси.

При этом вам не хочется уродовать свой `go.mod` инструкцией `replace`. Тогда создайте каталог `workspace`, в нём два подкаталога - `workspace/myapp` и `workspace/mylib`. В `myapp` поместите исходники приложения, а в `mylib` исходники библиотеки. Затем в каталоге `workspace` выполните команды

```
go work init
go work use ./mylib
go work use ./myapp
```

и вуаля! магия воркспейсов заработала. Теперь пакет с именем `example.org/mylib/root/cmd` будет найден в каталоге `workspace/mylib/root/cmd`.

[1] Пакет `example.org/mylib/cmd/root_test` должен содержать тесты для пакета `example.org/mylib/cmd/root`